# Owl Carousel - width is calculated wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I have three responsive items (imgs), but every time the Owl-Carousel is loaded, the owl-wrapper width is two times the size of all images together. 
For example; if the images fullsize takes 1583 px, the owl-wrapper takes 1583 * 3 * 2 = 9498px, and all site takes this width, instead the full size (1583 px).

The issue:   <strike>http://nacionalempreendimen.web2144.uni5.net</strike>

HTML

```
<div id="promoted-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="assets/img/tmp/1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="assets/img/tmp/2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="assets/img/tmp/3.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#promoted-carousel .item img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

JS

```
$('#promoted-carousel').owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: 5000,
    stopOnHover: true,
    singleItem: true
});
```

**UPDATE**

I saw that when I put `#promoted-carousel` div out of `.page-wrapper` div, it works properly. But my knowledge of css it is not sufficient to understand why it works.

Comment: try to put at `#main` CSS this: `overflow: hidden` and see if works

Comment: @GiovanniPerillo #main or .main? I try in .main css, but didn`t work.

Comment: `#main`, the # means it is an ID, because when I inspected the element, it was the div before your carousel div. if it's overflow is hidden, then it will hide it if bigger than the 100%.

Comment: Which version of owl carousel you are using?

Comment: I hope the issue in not in Owl Carousel ! see this example http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/u0d8L2z7/

Comment: Do you have an updated URL for your code?

Comment: Set the items to 1 will solve it (in my case).

Comment: if you managed to fix it with a workaround why not write your workaround code ?

Answer (score 3):

it helped me:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#promoted-carousel').owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 5000,
        stopOnHover: true,
        singleItem: true
    });
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

this solution helped me too , if your theme is using bootstrape 4 and the owl plugin is using  bootstrape 3 this will fix the owl width issue

```
 setTimeout(function() {
$('#promoted-carousel').owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: 5000,
    stopOnHover: true,
    singleItem: true
});
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

I often use 2 wrappers when working with Owl Carousel. I'd set all my styles per-slide for their height/width etc and the outer wrapper I'd set for the stage width etc.

I then call owl carousel on the inner wrapper and I usually have very few problems

```
<div id="promoted-carousel-outer">
    <div id="promoted-carousel">
        <div class="item"><img src="assets/img/tmp/1.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="assets/img/tmp/2.jpg"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="assets/img/tmp/3.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a known issue. You need to put `table-layout: fixed` on the table.

https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/issues/274

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievably, I suspect that this might be a bug within owlCarousel.

What helped me was removing the `* 2` in `appendWrapperSizes`:

```
    appendWrapperSizes : function () {
        var base = this,
            width = base.$owlItems.length * base.itemWidth;

        base.$owlWrapper.css({
            "width": width,//Comment out this part=> * 2,
            "left": 0
        });
        base.appendItemsSizes();
    },
```

This worked for owlCarousel 1.3.3.